# Did anybody come across this Lie algebra representation?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be – for the sake of simplicity – a complex Lie Algebra. Then we define the antisymmetric linear transformations as
$$
\mathfrak{A(g)} =\big\{\left.\,\alpha \in \mathfrak{gl(g)}\,\right|\;[\alpha(X),Y]+[X,\alpha(Y)]=0\text{ for all }X,Y\in \mathfrak{g}\,\big\}
$$
which is again a Lie algebra, and via $X.\alpha :=[\operatorname{ad}X,\alpha]$ a $\mathfrak{g}$-module.

It can be shown by direct calculation, that $\mathfrak{A(g)}=0$ for semisimple Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$, and $\mathfrak{A(g)}\neq 0$ for solvable Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$, where the one dimensional ideal is used.

As $\mathfrak{A(g)}=\mathfrak{gl(g)}$ for abelian Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$, the complexity of $\mathfrak{A(g)}$ somehow measures the complexity of $\mathfrak{g}$ in reverse, which makes it interesting for solvable Lie algebras without center. Being a Lie algebra itself it also allows all combinations like a semidirect product with $\mathfrak{g}$, iterations of $\mathfrak{A}(.)$, or other funny things like defining $(X,Y)\longmapsto \alpha([X,Y])$ as new Lie product.

Where can I find more about this?

Comment: You mean (nonzero) finite-dimensional solvable Lie algebras? For $\infty$-dimensional solvable Lie algebra there's not always a 1-dimensional ideal. Also strange remark, but the definition doesn't make use of the Lie bracket of the source. So it makes sense inside linear maps $\mathfrak{v}\to\mathfrak{g}$ for an arbitrary vector space $\mathfrak{v}$ (but for $\mathfrak{v}=\mathfrak{g}$ indeed one gets a Lie subalgebra of the Lie algebra of linear endomorphisms).

Comment: Yes, I meant finite dimensional cases. What do you mean by "doesn't make use of the Lie bracket of the source"? It is defined by the Lie bracket of the source $\mathfrak{g}$. It is an invariant of $\mathfrak{g}$, which is somewhere in between $0$ and $\mathfrak{gl(g)}$. As the structure constants of $\mathfrak{g}$ define the linear equation system which determines $\mathfrak{A(g)}$, there is a direct connection between them. E.g. if $\mathfrak{g}$ is the matrix algebra of first row only matrices, then $\mathfrak{g}\cong \mathfrak{A(g)}$.

Comment: It has a lot of funny properties. E.g. $[\alpha(X),[Y,Z]]+[\alpha(Y),[Z,X]]+[\alpha(Z),[X,Y]]=0$ (IIRC) which offers variations of Chevalley-Eilenberg cohomologies. I asked because I don't know any books which deal with - at least an attempt - to classify solvable Lie algebras. I only found something about low dimensional nilpotent ones, but the center is a bit disturbing here as it only adds free parameters.

Comment: Oops, I'm wrong (in my "strange remark"), it's senseless to copy the definition to maps from a vector space to $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: An extension of your assertion on semisimple Lie algebras: Let $W(\mathfrak{g})$ be the set of $x$ such that $B(x,[y,z])=0$ for all $y,z\in\mathfrak{g}$ and every invariant symmetric bilinear form (ISBF) on $\mathfrak{g}$. Then for every $\alpha\in\mathfrak{A}(\mathfrak{g})$ we have $\alpha$ valued in $W(\mathfrak{g})$. In general $W(\mathfrak{g})$ contains the center, but in case $\mathfrak{g}$ has a non-degenerate ISBF (there are many examples beyond semisimples), then it's an equality, and in particular if in addition the center is trivial then $\mathfrak{A}(\mathfrak{g})=0$.

Comment: Don't mind with the center. The subspace of linear maps from $\mathfrak{g}$ to its center is, in a sense, the "trivial part" of the subspace $\mathfrak{A}(\mathfrak{g})$. If you make computations, just choose a complementary subspace and consider maps into it. In addition, since clearly every $\alpha\in\mathfrak{A}(\mathfrak{g})$ maps the  center into the center, the relevant part (the quotient $\mathfrak{A}'(\mathfrak{g})$ by the trivial part) can be viewed as a subspace of the space of linear endomorphisms of $\mathfrak{g}/Z(\mathfrak{g})$. For ex., for Heisenberg we get $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

Comment: The Borel subalgebras of simple Lie algebras (except the one of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ which also results in $\mathfrak{sl}_2$) only have the $\alpha$ defined by the ideal $\langle  X\rangle$: $[X,Y]=\lambda(Y)X \text{ and } \alpha(Y)=\lambda(Y)X$. It always comes to: the more complex $\mathfrak{g}$ the less complex $\mathfrak{A(g)}$ and vice versa. But I can't find a tool to go deeper. The lack of a non degenerate bilinear form is a true handicap, and of course the fact that $\mathfrak{A}(.)$ doesn't respect ideals.

Comment: Beware that Borel subalgebras of semisimple Lie algebras are very non-typical solvable Lie algebras (and their nilpotent radical is very non-typical as nilpotent Lie algebras). Still, observations: every $\alpha\in\mathfrak{A}(\mathfrak{g})$ preserves the ascending central series. Also, whenever it preserves an ideal, it preserves its centralizer (and more generally its centralizer modulo another $\alpha$-invariant ideal).

Comment: ... and also if $I$ is an ideal, then $\alpha$ maps $I$ into $\{x:\forall y:[x,y]\in I\}$ (the inverse image of the center of $\mathfrak{g}/I$). In particular, every ideal $I$ such that $\mathfrak{g}/I$ has trivial center, is invariant: this applies in particular to the solvable radical of a finite-dimensional Lie algebra.

Comment: ... and also if $I$ is an ideal, then $\alpha$ maps $I$ into $\{x:\forall y:[x,y]\in I\}$ (the inverse image of the center of $\mathfrak{g}/I$). In particular, every ideal $I$ such that $\mathfrak{g}/I$ has trivial center, is invariant: this applies in particular to the solvable radical of a finite-dimensional Lie algebra. In turn since in a semisimple Lie algebra (in char. zero) any map with the condition (give a name, similar to "derivation"?) is zero, it means that it takes values in the radical.

Comment: They once arose from the investigation of the algorithmical variety structure of Lie multiplications where they were called antisymmetric (in contrast to symmetric $[\sigma(X),X]=0$ and isometric for the tensored triple $\chi([\varphi(X),\psi(Y)])=[X,Y]$). It was a boring standalone definition, the symmetric ones were the interesting transformations.

Comment: But applied to solvable Lie algebras I found that they lead to many new areas. Questions like: Which towers can we get from $\mathfrak{A(.)}$: cycles, stabilities, infinite ones etc? Also as $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{A(g)}$ are somehow complementary in their structure, what about their semidirect product?

Comment: Beware that "antisymmetric linear transformation" already has a meaning in the presence of a scalar product, which makes it confusing.

Comment: I know, but the confusion should be minimal in absence of a canonical inner product. The definition is somehow the same, only with Lie brackets instead of 'scalar' brackets. It made sense as a term in the realm of bilinear algorithms $\sum u_k^* \otimes v_k^* \otimes W_k$.

Comment: I find something with "derivative" worse, because we don't have a boundary operator, and the functorial properties are very different. Furthermore, it falsely would seduce to think that they are simply derivations with $\mathfrak{g}'$ in the kernel.

Comment: Of course deriv(...) is worse, I never suggested it. There are plenty of words that could be used (transfiguration, transmutation, mutation, metamorphosis, transference, etc– just browse a dictionary of synonyms, e.g., [here](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/transform?s=t)); I also thought of "paraderivation". The problem with 'antisymmetric' is that whenever you specify to a Lie algebra which has a scalar product, you get a clumsy terminology.

Comment: para+... sounds good!. It pleases the anarchistic child in me. ;-)

Comment: Another remark: this space is not only "invariant" under Lie algebra isomorphisms, but under "post-isomorphism": if we post-compose the bracket by some linear automorphism, then the new Lie algebra (if it satisfies Jacobi) has isomorphic space of paraderivations. [Note: a more general setting where this makes sense is that of spaces $\mathfrak{g}$ endowed with a skew-symmetric bilinear map into another space.] E.g., there are continuum many 3-dim Lie algebras ($\mathfrak{g}_t$ with basis $(u,x,y)$, $[u,x]=x,[u,y]=ty,[x,y]=0$ up to $t\mapsto 1/t$, but all are post-isomorphic for $t\neq 0$.